# how can I transform type of variables in IMP

Tags: objective-c

How can I transform type of variables when I try to use IMP?

```
Person.m
-(void)priFunc:(NSString *)str{
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

I use IMP get priFunc,then I want to implement the function

```
main.m

...
IMP imp = method_getImplementation(method);

typedef void(*fn)(id,SEL,char *);
fn f = (fn)imp;
f(person,sel,"Jason");
```

The question is the type of variable str in *Person.m* is `NSString`,but the type of variable in pointer fn is `char*` . Though build succeeded, the program will give `(lldb)` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a function that takes an `NSString *` argument and pass it a `char *` and expect it to work.  The two types aren't compatible.

You need to convert the `char *` argument to an object or rewrite the method to take a `char *`.